# Custom regular expression for string with number

Tags: c#, regex

I have to validate a sting with regular expression.
String Should be in the NHCC-XXXXX-00 Format ,where X is a Number.

Correct strings:

```
NHCC-10010-00,
NHCC-78965-00,
NHCC-99654-00
```

Wrong strings:

```
NHCC-1001-00
NHCC-78965-0
NHC-99654-00
ASDF-99654-00
NHCC-F9654-00
NHCC-99654-01
```

Can any one help me to solve the above senario?

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: If you ever need to write "custom" in your question title, don't post it on stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
"NHCC-\d{5}-00"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX6fJ7/3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use anchors inorder to do an exact match.

```
@"^NHCC-\d{5}-00$"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you want is `@"(?s)^NHCC-\d{5}-00$"`

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"(?s)^NHCC-\d{5}-00$"))
{
    //not valid
}
```